# Need to write a C++ function that searches for a specific element in a binary tree

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

Need to write a C++ function that searches for elements with the value of the zodiac_sign field specified by the user in the binary tree and if there is no such element, print the corresponding message.

I have written the following code:

```
void findZodiacSign(tree* top, char zodiac_sign[10]) {
    if (top == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    int comparisonResult = std::strcmp(top->inf.zodiac_sign, zodiac_sign);

    if (comparisonResult == 0) {
        // Если значения совпадают, выводим информацию об элементе
        printf("| %10d | %7s | %5s | %10s | %d/%d/%d |\n", top->inf.id, top->inf.last_name, top->inf.first_name, top->inf.zodiac_sign, top->inf.date_of_birth[0], top->inf.date_of_birth[1], top->inf.date_of_birth[2]);
    }
    else {
        cout << "This element does not exist" << endl;
    }

    findZodiacSign(top->left, zodiac_sign);
    findZodiacSign(top->right, zodiac_sign);
}
```

And I have such a problem that I get several messages that such an element does not exist even if the element was found. I guess that this is because of recursion, but I don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: You should not output "This element does not exist" if you are still planning to make recursive calls. You should only print that when all the searching has been completed.

Comment: You can't say that something isn't found until you've completed the search. How could you know you've searched the entire tree?

Comment: If this is a binary tree, you shouldn't have to search the whole tree. Your recurison should decide which branch to search next based on the sign of `comparisonResult`.

Comment: The tool of choice for a problem like this is not a Stack Overflow question. It's [a debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger). With a debugger you can run the program at your speed and watch exactly what it does as it does it. As soon as you see the program do something you didn't expect, you've found a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick refactor of your code. Do the recursive searching independent of the printing of the result, else it gets tricky trying to determine when to show the "not found" message.

A couple of other recommendations. Pass zodiac_sign as `const char*`.  The `char[10]` member of the struct will automatically cast to `const char*` (because all arrays become pointers when passed a parameters).  Even better if you can use `std::string` and pass as `const std::string&`  Also, don't mix cout and printf.  I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

```
tree* findZodiacSignImpl(tree* top, const char* zodiac_sign) {

    if (top == nullptr) {
         return nullptr;
    }

    int comparisonResult = std::strcmp(top->inf.zodiac_sign, zodiac_sign);
    if (comparisonResult == 0) {
        return top;
    }

    tree* node = findZodiacSignImpl(top->left, zodiac_sign);
    if (node == nullptr) {
        node = findZodiacSignImpl(top->right, zodiac_sign);
    }
    return node;
}

void findZodiacSign(tree* top, const char* zodiac_sign) {
    tree* node = findZodiacSignImpl(top, zodiac_sign);
    if (node == nullptr) {
        cout << "This element does not exist" << endl;
    } else {
        printf("| %10d | %7s | %5s | %10s | %d/%d/%d |\n", node->inf.id, node->inf.last_name, node->inf.first_name, node->inf.zodiac_sign, node->inf.date_of_birth[0], node->inf.date_of_birth[1],node->inf.date_of_birth[2]);
    }

}
```